# How can I fit two linear regression in the same data?

Tags: r, statistics

Might sound dumb, but let's say I have:

```
x = c(1:10)
y = c(2,4,6,8,10,12,12.5,13,13.5,14)
```

the scatterplot looks like this:

[image]

Instead of fitting one linear regression I would like to fit two linear regressions eq. 1 when x > ***a*** and eq. 2 when x <= ***a***. And also find the ***a*** value from when the slop change. In this example ***a*** would be around 6 from a visual analysis, but is there a way to find it more automatically?

what I am looking is something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CRAN package [segmented](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/index.html) is perfect for this kind of problem. It's even simple to use. First fit a linear model, then get the segmented fit.

```
library(segmented)

x <- 1:10
y <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,12.5,13,13.5,14)

fit <- lm(y ~ x)
segfit <- segmented(fit)
```

Now the break point. `segfit$psi[2]` is the break point.

```
segfit$psi
#       Initial Est.       St.Err
#psi1.x     5.5    6 6.452643e-16
```

The summary gives more information.

```
summary(segfit)
```

And plot the graph.

```
plot(x, y)
plot(segfit, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you plot :

```
scatter.smooth(x,y)
```

you can get a line :
[stating where is your break point or threshold point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxnzT.png)

Apart from that you can you for loop to check where slope is getting changed :

```
for(i in 1:length(x)){
slope = (y[i+1]-y[i]/(x[i+1]-x[i]))
  print(paste(i,slope))
}
```

Hope this helps.

[r](/questions/tagged/r) [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics)

Comment: Thanks Tushar, that helps. Relatively easy way to spot the change.